# VisualStudio зависает на "Получении текста подсказки (DataTip) по данным"

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio

Пишу шахматы в юнити. Пытаясь отдебажить код, наткнулся на такую проблему: то тут, то там VisualStudio зависает намертво, а посреди экрана появляется окно с надписью "Получение текста подсказки (DataTip) по данным".

Заметил закономерность, что зависание происходит не когда идешь дебагом от строки к строке, а ставишь где-то впереди точку останова и нажимаешь "Продолжить": выполнение доходит до точки останова и останавливается. Полностью...

Первый раз встречаюсь с такой проблемой, по тексту надписи в интернете ничего не нашел
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предлагаю зарепортить баг непосредственно по [студии](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).